# unexpected tFID error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a lists controller

```
def destroy
    if params[:listtype] == 'shopping_cart_items'
        removeFromList!(params[:id], ListItem.shopping_cart)
        redirect_to controller: 'browse_courses', action: 'show', type: 'courses', id: params[:id]
    elsif params[:listtype] == 'currently_taking_items'
        removeFromList!(params[:id], ListItem.currently_taking)
        redirect_to user_path(current_user.id, tab: 'current')
    end
end
```

With removeFromList! defined as follows

```
def removeFromList!(course_id, type)
   current_user.list_items.where(course_id: course_id, list_type: type).destroy
end
```

When I get redirected to this action I get the following error and I can't figure out why!

```
../app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting ')' removeFromList!(item.course.id, ListItem.shopping_cart) ^
```

Comment: you have a syntax error in your controller in line 11. please post the whole controller code, or at least line 1 to 11.

Answer (score 0):

Oops I thought the error was in the destroy action and totally overlooked it many thanks! At first I couldn't find a missing ')' but it was in a whole different part of my code.